# Timer instantely stops

Tags: c#, timer

Hi I have 2 questions.

1. My timer stops immediately and if it doesn't it does not pick up the given interval.

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClashRoyaleHack
{
    public partial class GoldCMD : Form
    {
        public GoldCMD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer2.Interval = 10000;
            timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            timer2.Start();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
 }
```

2. On creating the code I notices a slight difference. I am using almost identical forms with the same content but different names and different timer names etc. But one does work with the timer and same code (using ofcourse different names for the timer and form etc) but the other doesn't...
   Really weird. Hopefully you guys can help me out. The code above does not have the private void GoldCMD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) But just the normal private void GoldCMD(object sender, EventArgs e) maybe that has something to do with it.

Code of the one that does work:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClashRoyaleHack
{
    public partial class GemsCMD : Form
    {
        public GemsCMD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GemsCMD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 7500;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the timer "instantly stops" ?

Comment: I don't I'm assuming as the form instantely closes and that is what there is at the timer2_Tick.

Comment: Can you show the rest of that timer's setup?

Comment: Okay I will update the main thread in a few seconds with the other one that does work.

Comment: Okay its  updated, as you can see there, there is a private void GemsCMD_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) that the GoldCMD does not have.

Comment: I doubt that will make a difference. Interstig would be the part where the Timers are declared and I am sure, there are more Properties being set.

Comment: The properties of both timers are exactly the same except for the name ofcourse.

Comment: Daaah, I am stupid. Actually, **it does make the difference** ! The Load event is fired right before the Form is first displayed. The Constructor can of course be called much earlier!

Comment: So this has something to do with the private void GoldCMD_Load not being there?

Comment: I am pretty sure, yes. If everything else is identical. Then the time of starting the timer is different if you start it in the ctor or in the Load-EventHandler. Luckily, you can easily add one to your GoldCMD-Form :)

Comment: Just by simply copying the one from the GemsCMD and pasting it into GoldCMD? And then just changing the code a bit ofcourse.

Comment: Not exactly, you also have to register the event. You are using Visual Studio right?

Comment: When in the Designer for GoldCMD Form, in the Properties Box there should be an icon that looks like a lightning. It's for Events. If you click it, you will be presented with a list of events that the form provides. By doubleclicking in the empty field next to "Load" the IDE will create and register an event handler for you and jump to the implementation to be filled by you (that will be the private void GoldCMD_Load).

Comment: Yes I am. If you could explain me how to do this as I'm kind of noob and getting into using timers etc. I'm also not to familiar with the program itself but I know the basics

Comment: Alright thanks I did that. Going for a test run.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work... The timer does not stop after the given interval.

Comment: Did you move the timer2 code into the Load-EventHandler (and removed it from Constructor)?

Comment: I removed timer2 from the "copied" Load event. And after creating the good one I pasted it in again. What do you mean by Constructor?

Answer (score -1):

### The Solution:

It is conceivable that the timer may "tick" once upon starting and considering your code closes it immediately after a tick, it is likely the source of your issue. Otherwise if that is not the reasoning, then you are still killing it at its first tick regardless of time.

Comment: That would be "**The Reason**" not "**The Solution**" ... just to be a little nitpicky.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` doesn't fire the `Tick` event immediately, actually none of the timers available do that

Comment: @Pixel There must be something more to it, from the code given both should work as expected

Comment: Okay I found a weird little thingy in the main form (form1)
I will update the main thread with this.

Comment: Updated the main thread with the weird piece of code only being there for the Gems form.

Comment: Sorry @Fildor also it was just a thought was unsure if he had a modified class.